# Calling a method in the while loop condition

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm curious is it possible to call a method that returns a boolean value in the condition part of a while loop?

As in:

```
    while(someMethod()!= true){
          //Do stuff
    }
```

And the method simply returns a true or false. Is this possible or not and if so is there a correct syntax or a better way?

Edit: Thanks for the quick responses. As an extension to my question is it possible to call the method multiple times for different things but require them all to be the same before exiting the loop?

For example:

```
while(!(someMethod(input_a) == someMethod(input_b))){
    //Do stuff
}
```

Where both of the returned values are the returned values are equal?

Comment: It is possible, and you basically got it right, although `while(!someMethod())` would be more conventional.

Comment: Have you actually tried doing this? That's the easiest way to find out if something is possible. If you find it's not, then you can post the actual errors in a question.

Comment: @AndyTurner I have but it doesn't seem to be working as intended. This code is supposed to be part of a battleship game and this while loop is intended to test whether or not two ships overlap. It seems to not work as I would like ie the ships overlap each other. The thing is the issue only comes up when I try to call the method more than once in the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you

```
public boolean functionOne(int i){
   // some operation
   if(i == 1) return true;
   else return false;
}

public void otherFunc(){
   int i = 0;
   if(functionOne(i)) { // e.g: if(functionOne(i) == true)
      // your code
      // 0!=1 so result is fort 
   }
   if(!functionOne(i)){ // e.g: if(functionOne(i) == false) 
     // your code
     // 0!=1 it is false, but ! before functionOne negate so ! of false is true
   } 

   // **for your while**
   while(functionOne(i)){ // while function returns true
    // code 
   }
   // **or**
   while(!functionOne(i)){ // while function returns false
    // code 
   }
}
```

Comment: Of course, in your simplistic example an `else` would be better.  I know that you are displaying for educational purposes only though.

Comment: yep there should be else as you say :)

Answer (score 0):

Less is best:

```
while (!someMethod()) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

It's never a good idea to compare to a boolean result to a boolean literal. Prefer using the result in-line, using the logical unary not operator `!` as required.

---

Answering the now-edited version of the question, less is still best:

```
while (someMethod(input_a) != someMethod(input_b))
```

Comment: Does it actually make a difference in performance, or is just because it's unnecessary clutter and not according to the convention?

Comment: @Gendarme Mainly clutter, but also a style that avoids the insidious "accidental assignment" bug: compare `if (a == true)` with `if (a = true)`. Both compile and execute, but one is obviously a bug. Although you can't assign to a method result, it's just good practice to always follow this style. You should extend it to prefer `return myBooleanMethod();` over `if (myBooleanMethod()) return true; else return false;` et al

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course!

```
public static boolean someMethod(){
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    while(!someMethod()){
        //do something
        System.out.println("Hi");
     }
  }
```

Like in this code, an infinite loop will be called if the method returns false, but if the method returns true, it will just come out of the while loop. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the specification of the while loop in [JLS Sec 14.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.12):

> The while statement executes an Expression and a Statement repeatedly until the value of the Expression is false.
>
> ```
> WhileStatement:
>     while ( Expression ) Statement
> WhileStatementNoShortIf:
>     while ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf
> ```
>
> The Expression must have type boolean or Boolean, or a compile-time error occurs.

So, you can use anything which is an [`Expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-Expression) of type `boolean` (or `Boolean`).

And if you click through the productions in the language spec:

- [`Expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-Expression), contains
- [`AssignmentExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-AssignmentExpression), contains
- [`ConditionalExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ConditionalExpression), contains
- [`ConditionalOrExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ConditionalOrExpression), contains
- [`ConditionalAndExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ConditionalAndExpression), contains
- [`InclusiveOrExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-InclusiveOrExpression), contains
- [`ExclusiveOrExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ExclusiveOrExpression), contains
- [`AndExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-AndExpression), contains
- [`EqualityExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-EqualityExpression), contains
- [`RelationalExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-RelationalExpression), contains
- [`ShiftExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ShiftExpression), contains
- [`AdditiveExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-AdditiveExpression), contains
- [`MultiplicativeExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-MultiplicativeExpression), contains
- [`UnaryExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-UnaryExpression), contains
- [`UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus), contains
- [`PostfixExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-PostfixExpression), contains
- [`Primary`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-Primary), contains
- [`PrimaryNoNewArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-PrimaryNoNewArray), contains
- [`MethodInvocation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-MethodInvocation)

Phew! That's pretty deeply buried! (You can read this like an inheritance hierarchy, so every `MethodInvocation` is a `PrimaryNoNewArray`, and every `PrimaryNoNewArray` is a `Primary` etc).

So, transitively, every `MethodInvocation` is an `Expression`, hence it's fine to use it as the expression in a `while` loop.

---

Addressing your edit: yes, that's fine too. If you look at the detail of the `EqualityExpression`:

```
EqualityExpression:
    RelationalExpression 
    EqualityExpression == RelationalExpression 
    EqualityExpression != RelationalExpression
```

As already described above, you can use an `EqualityExpression` as the `Expression` in a `WhileStatement`. And something of the form

```
RelationalExpression != RelationalExpression
```

is an `EqualityExpression` by the rule shown. Since all `MethodInvocation`s are `RelationalExpression`s, you can use method invocations in the while statement as you've shown:

```
while(someMethod(input_a) != someMethod(input_b)) {
```

(`a != b` is an easier way of writing `!(a == b)`).

Answer (score -1):

This is the way we have done loops over java iterators.  For instance:

```
Iterator[String] iterator = util.Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three").iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    println(iterator.next());
}
```

We have also done something similar for the JDBC ResultSet interface.